# how get this selector in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to apply a click event to each a on list here is my code for the second a , i need to get each selector :

```
<div class="slick-track">
    <li id="thumbnail_141" class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active">
        <a class="magictoolbox-selector mz-thumb-selected mz-thumb"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="thumbnail_141" class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active">
        <a class="magictoolbox-selector mz-thumb-selected mz-thumb"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="thumbnail_141" class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active">
        <a class="magictoolbox-selector mz-  thumb-selected mz-thumb"></a>
    </li>
</div>
```

I tryed this:

```
$('.slick-track li:nth-child(2) a').click();
```

Comment: `$('.slick-track>li>a')` so you want this ?

Comment: Simply `$('.slick-track a')` or `$('a.magictoolbox-selector')`!

Answer (score 3):

You can write "global" events. You don't have to write it for every specific "a".

```
$(".slick-track").on("click", "a", function(){
   //your code here
})
```

To access the element that was clicked:
in `this` you have element you clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle I put together to hopefully help you... ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kha35no8/)).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // LISTENER FOR CLICKS ON ANY OF THE LI ELEMENTS...
    $('.slick-track li a').on('click', function(){
            // WHEN CLICKED, SHOW THE TEXT CONTENT FOR THIS ITEM
                alert($(this).text())
    });

  // PERFORM A CLICK ON THE ** SECOND ** LIST ITEM A ELEMENT
    $('.slick-track li:nth-child(2) a').click();  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

i used

```
$('.slick-track li:nth-child(3) a img').css("background-color", "yellow");
$('.slick-track li:nth-child(3) a').css("background-color", "yellow");
$('.slick-track li:nth-child(3)').css("background-color", "yellow");
```

its work but when i try click event nothing happen !

```
$('.slick-track li:nth-child(3) a img').click();
$('.slick-track li:nth-child(3) a').click();
$('.slick-track li:nth-child(3)').click();
```